# How to rotate a rectangle around centroid in flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, matrix, actionscript, flex3

I am using matrix.rotate method to rotate the rectangle (box in my case). 
   My rotate event looks like below

public function transformObject(transformEvent:TransformEvent):void{

```
        var numChildrn:int = _markedObjectLayer.numChildren;
        var tempMatrix: Matrix = null;
        var tempx:Number;
        var tempy:Number;
        var tempHeight:Number;
        var tempWidth:Number;
        for(var i:int = 0; i < numChildrn; i++){
            var chld:MarkedObject = ObjectLayer.getChildAt(i)
            if (chld.selected){
                var  height:int = (BoxObject) chld.height;
                var  width:int = (BoxObject) chld.width;


                tempMatrix = chld.transform.matrix;


                tempHeight=height;  
                tempWidth=width;


                tempMatrix = MatrixTransformer.transform(tempMatrix,transformEvent.angle);


                tempMatrix.tx=tempx;
                tempMatrix.ty=tempy

                chld.transform.matrix = tempMatrix;
            }
        }

        invalidateDisplayList();
    }
}
```

The Matrix.transform method calls matrix.rotate method

public static function transform(sourceMatrix:Matrix,
                                         rotation:Number=0 ):Matrix 
        {

```
        sourceMatrix = MatrixTransformer.rotate(sourceMatrix, rotation, "degrees");

        return sourceMatrix;
    }



    /**
     * Rotates a matrix and returns the result. The unit parameter lets the user specify "degrees", 
     * "gradients", or "radians". 
     */
    public static function rotate(sourceMatrix:Matrix, angle:Number, unit:String = "radians"):Matrix {
        if (unit == "degrees") 
        {
            angle = Math.PI * 2 *( angle / 360);
        }

        sourceMatrix. rotate(angle)
        return sourceMatrix;
    }
```

The issue is that x and y are left corener of the box and hence it is rotating around left corner. However, if I try to give temp.x and temp.y as centroid value it does not rotate around centroid?

Can any one suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks
Akshay

Comment: This is enahncement of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814859/rotating-of-box-in-flex3-using-matrix-transformation-about-center?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It appears that I was not translating them to appropriate coordinate positions before and after rotation

//Step 1 Fix the co-ordinates of rectangle . I added them to an event so that they remain  static

```
    if (TransformEvent.X == 0 && TransformEvent.Y == 0)
        {
         TransformEvent.X = chld.x;
           TransformEvent.Y = chld.y;
         }
```

//next get the  centroid of rectangle

```
       tempx = TransformEvent.X + width/2;
       tempy= TransformEvent.Y +height/2;
```

// Step 3: translate before rotation

```
        tempMatrix.translate(-1*tempx,-1*tempy);
```

//Rotate the rectangle

```
        tempMatrix = MatrixTransformer.transform(tempMatrix,transformEvent.angle);
```

//translate to centroid after rotation

```
         tempMatrix.translate(tempx,tempy);
```

//assign back the matrix to the rectangle

```
         chld.transform.matrix = tempMatrix;
```

Thanks for all your help. Also the this site helped me with translation bit 
http://www.foxarc.com/blog/article/66.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you really want or have to use matrices directly, you can do this more conveniently using a built-in flash class: `fl.motion.MatrixTransformer`:

```
MatrixTransformer.rotateAroundInternalPoint(matrix, centroidX, centroidY, angleInDegrees);
```

See the Adobe [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/MatrixTransformer.html#rotateAroundInternalPoint%28%29) on `MatrixTransformer` for more information.

However, if you don't *need* to use the transformation matrix, the simpler solution would be to:

- have your objects drawn in such a way that (0, 0) is their centroid
- use the simple `rotation` property from `DisplayObject` which achieves the same goal in a much simpler manner

Comment: Thanks Jakub for your reply. But is fl.motion.MatrixTransformer available in flex to import? I tried to look but there was no such library available. Am I supposed to download some library?

Comment: I have not imported the fl library , however the object is moving in a spiral motion after each rotation..I shall post the code soon